# Choose a package for a tcp client with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, npm, client

I need to use a node package to create a TCP client.
I already searched on npm.

What package do you recommend ?

I don't need to create a server or anything. Just want to write on a server with my client.

Comment: Why not just use the built in [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) package?

Comment: So i just need these two functions ? 

https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_address
https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_write_data_encoding_callback

Comment: There's an example in the [net.connect](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_connect_options_connectlistener) section, you can use that to start.

Comment: Ok, 
So if i don't want to work with localhost i have to use  `code` net.createConnection(port[, host][, connectListener]) right ?

Comment: http://www.hacksparrow.com/tcp-socket-programming-in-node-js.html
Thanks for your help, i found what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hacksparrow.com/tcp-socket-programming-in-node-js.html 
Found solution to my problem.